# Curve loses animation data when converted to mesh

Tags: animation, mesh, bezier-curves

I have a curve simply animated in my scene. I have converted the curve to a mesh and once I do that, the mesh doesn't have any of the original curve's animation data applied to it (although the mesh technically has keyframes). **How can I apply the animation data from the curve to the mesh?**

Comment: what kind of animation was it? Could you please show some screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might benefit from *Join as Shapes*. Please see the below gif:

(Note: This method works with former beveled curves that were animated with either *Shape Keys* or *Hooks*, but please be advised that it doesn't seem to interpolate precisely the same way curves do, although you can ostensibly get *closer* by "sampling" more frames):

[image: "Join as Shapes" Method]
Hope this helps! Peace and God bless!